# Interposing code into an existing apk

Tags: android, apk, function-interposition, library-interposition, interposing

Is it possible, given an existing apk, to interpose method calls? What about arbitrary lines of code?

Ideally I would like to be able to intercept a method call/line of code and call my  own method to do some checks or logging and then let the original execution continue without altering the original behavior.

If this is possible, can somebody please point me in the right direction to some reading material?

Thanks

Comment: This is not possible, except perhaps on rooted devices, for blindingly obvious privacy and security reasons. For development, a debugger would have some possibilities here.

Comment: The security reasons make sense. Thank you.